# DirectAdmin Centos4 server has virus

Tags: linux, centos, malware

I have a problem with a webserver that runs Centos4 with DirectAdmin.

Since a few weeks some websites hosted on it are not redirecting on search engines properly, they are redirected to some malware site, resulting in a ban from google.

Now I have used 3 virusscanners:
ClamAV: Didn't find anything
Bitdefender: Found a 2-3 files with JS infection, deleted them
AVG: Finds lots of files, but doesn't have the option to clean!

The virus that it finds is:
JS/Redir
JS/Dropper

Still the strange thing is: website a (www.aa.com) does not have any infected files (have gone through all the files manually, is a custom PHP app, nothing special) but does still have the same virus. Website b (www.bb.com) does have the infected files as only one.

I deleted all these files and suspended the account, but no luck, still the same error.

I do get the log entries on the website from the searchengines so the DNS entries are not changed.

But now I have gone through the httpd files but cannot find anything.

Where can I start looking for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is with the web server and not with the website itself?  Perhaps the virus modified a script so that you can't detect the changes with a virus detector?

Comment: this may be the case.

Comment: I think this is the case too, but where to look? My httpd.conf is fine, and the includes in that file look OK too. No funny stuff in there.

Comment: It might help to reinstall Apache and it's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

run [chkrootkit](http://www.chkrootkit.org/) and/or [Rootkit Hunter](http://www.rootkit.nl/projects/rootkit_hunter.html) I suspect that jmort253 is right and the server has been compromised. did you check for any funny .htacces files or conf files?

Comment: Yeah I checked, but because DirectAdmin is on the server it's hell to look for a problem, I am not familiar with all scripts so actual DA scripts can look suspicious. RK hunter gave no results luckily.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the binaries have been compromised. Difficult to contain, but not impossible.  I'd def suggest backing up sites ONLY to a known good server - NOT keeping them on the same box.